# Database design for Order Management

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

I would like to know the best practice for designing the database for an Order Management System. I have an order table and orderitems table.
My current design is as follows.

```
   Order table

   orderid       int    primary key
   totalprice    int
   orderstatus   int 

   Order Items table

   orderitemid   int    primary key
   orderid       int    foreign key
   productid     int
   quantity      int
```

The orderid is the foreign key here.
An order a number of order items in the order items table.
Its a one to many relationship.

Is this the best method for designing the tables or should is use the below design

```
   Order table

   id            int     primary key
   orderid       int
   orderitemid   int     foreign key
   totalprice    int
   orderstatus   int 

   Order Items table

   orderitemid   int     primary key
   productid     int
   quantity      int
```

Please describe the advantages and disadvantages in using both designs.
Also let me know if some other better designs are possible.

Comment: The 2nd design is clearly wrong as it only allows an order to have at most *one* item.

Comment: Please suggest me with a good alternative.

Comment: @user2864740, that's not the case. orderid is not the primary key.

Comment: Read the Data Model REssource BOok, Volume 1 - order management, inventory management are part of the standard schemas explained there.

Comment: @Mau Good catch, and to which I must respond: then it's even more broken..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 is the only reasonable option

As 1 `Order` has many `Order Items`, the `orderId` is held once in `Orders` and many times in `Order Items`.

With Option 2, this relationship is possible but you would be duplicating data unnecessarily, as you wouldn't be able to have many `OrderItemId` values against one record in `Order`.

This is basic normalisation.

Comment: nothing wrong, but i like to know if any thing better is avaiable